# ASM TASM Printing, loops, screen cel coordinates

Tags: assembly, tasm

I've got a code herefor printing and looping strings, 
how would I go about printing the string starting at a specific (x,y) coordinate on the screen without using blank characters? What I mean is, I want to be able to specify the starting position for my print function rather than looping the code for printing a blank character until I get to the position I want.

```
.model small

.stack 100h

.data

string db "string$"

.code

main: 
mov cx, 3

l: 
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax
mov ah, 09h
mov dx, offset string
int 21h
loop l


mov ah, 4ch
int 21h 

end main
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically have two options:

1) If your terminal supports it you can output [ANSI escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to position the cursor before sending your string output.

2) You can write directly to video memory. If you set the graphics adapter to 80x25 color text mode, video memory will start at address 0xB800:0 and is made up of character/attribute pairs of bytes for each character - 4K in all.

Comment: great, what I need to do is write directly to video memory. If you have the time, do you think you could show me how to print my string db in the center of the screen, as an example? I'm having trouble figuring out how to use the interrupt for this. On [this](http://www.dcc.unicamp.br/~celio/mc404-2004/service_interrupts.html) page it says to use INT 10h while AH = 13h

Comment: There are numerous examples of this floating around. [Here's one](http://muruganad.com/8086/8086-Assembly-Writing-Directly-to-Video-Memory-B800.html).